# Error while importing selenium on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

So as it says in the title I have a problem with importing Selenium module on my Ubuntu laptop. On my Windows pc everything goes fine with basic Selenium code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

but when I try to do that on my Ubuntu machine I get an error that is basically saying:

```
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exception.WebDriverException:  Message:'geckodriver'executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Has anyone encoutered this problem and if yes does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to fix this is to download the driver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

**Method 1: Adding geckodriver to existing path folder**

Unzip the file and copy the "geckodriver" executable to "/usr/bin" using:

```
cd /folder/containing/geckodriver
sudo cp geckodriver /usr/bin
```

**Method 2: Adding custom geckodriver location to path**

You can also add the  driver in your system path temporarily with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

For a permanent solution, you can edit your bash profile with:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Then find the PATH line and modify it to look more like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver"
```